# Python select from sqlite3 in custom format

Tags: python, sqlite

I have this:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('./db/norviumscanner')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT email, password FROM users''')

users = cursor.fetchall()
print users

# Our mock database.
# users = {'email@gmail.com': {'password': 'password'}}
```

My output to `print users` is:

```
[(u'email@gmail.com', u'password')]
```

How can I match my output to my mock (users = {'email@gmail.com': {'password': 'password'}}) database example in the above code example? I must convert to something or I can make a more "special" select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't need comment

```
data = [(u'email@gmail.com', u'password')]

users = { row[0]:{'password':row[1]} for row in data }
```

or

```
users = { email:{'password':password} for email, password in data }
```